# Send fields to API After payment completed with Woocommerce And Gravity Forms Product Add-ons

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I've disabled all the default woocommerce billing and shipping and have created just these 2 fields **phone number** and **email address** with gravity forms, So these 2 fields shows on every product page with the help of **Gravity Forms Product Add-ons** for customers to fill when ordering a product.

I used to use gravity forms alone to do this on my old site that after payment completed do the example function below (with just gravity forms hooks gform_post_payment_completed):

```
//Send to API
function gfroms_after_payment_sms( $entry, $action ) {

    // for more info, check https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/entry-object/

    $url = 'https://thirdparty.com/api/v2/send';
    $apiKey = '00000000000';
    $headers = array('api-key: '.$apiKey);
    $from = 'Sender's Name';
    $to = [$entry['14']]; //phone number field ID
    $email = $entry['10.1']; //Email field ID
    $body = "blah blah blah $email and $to from $from"; 
    
    
    $data = array (
       'recipients' => $to,
       'sender' => $from,
       'message' => $body
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = http_build_query($result, TRUE);
    curl_close($ch);
    
}
// Tells the notification to be sent only when this hook is found and to include the arguments ($entry and $action)
add_action( 'gform_post_payment_completed', 'gfroms_after_payment_sms',  10, 2 );
```

Now how do I achieve this with woocommerce hooks woocommerce_payment_complete I've tried the below but its not working.

```
function custom_msg_customer_process_order( $order_id ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Quit early if not a valid order.
    if ( ! $order ) {
         return;
    }

    $url = 'https://thirdparty.com/api/v2/send';
    $apiKey = '00000000000';
    $headers = array('api-key: '.$apiKey);
    $from = 'Sender's Name';
    $to = [$entry['14']]; //phone number field ID
    $email = $entry['10.1']; //Email field ID
    $body = "blah blah blah $email and $to from $from"; 


    $data = array (
       'recipients' => $to,
       'sender' => $from,
       'message' => $body
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = http_build_query($result, TRUE);
    curl_close($ch);


add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_msg_customer_process_order' );
```

Please how do i make this work with woocommerce after payment has been made by the customer, Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you want this to work when orders are considered 'completed' or after any order is submitted (i.e. "processing', 'pending', etc.)?  If so, maybe try add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_msg_customer_process_order' ) instead of 'woocommerce_payment_complete'.  The woocommerce_thankyou hook runs after every order.

Comment: @Rochelle I want it only when orders are completed.

Comment: Got it.  So the first issue I see is that there is nothing that captures the entry id. Is the gravity form appearing for each item in the cart?  If so, you first have to loop through the order then grab the corresponding gravity form entry.

Comment: Yes it does, The 2 fields that's Phone number and email field appears in each item, On the loop kindly assist me on how to do it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_msg_customer_process_order' );
function custom_msg_customer_process_order( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // Quit early if not a valid order.
    if ( ! $order ) {
         return;
    }
    $cart_reg = $order->get_items();
    foreach( $cart_reg as $key => $value) { 
        $linked_entry=$value->get_meta( '_gravity_forms_history')["_gravity_form_linked_entry_id"]; 
        if (isset($linked_entry) && !empty($linked_entry)){
            $entry_id = $linked_entry;
            $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );
            if(!is_wp_error($entry)){
              $url = 'https://thirdparty.com/api/v2/send';
              $apiKey = '00000000000';
              $headers = array('api-key: '.$apiKey);
              $from = 'Sender's Name';
              $to = [$entry['14']]; //phone number field ID
              $email = $entry['10.1']; //Email field ID
              $body = "blah blah blah $email and $to from $from"; 

              $data = array (
               'recipients' => $to,
               'sender' => $from,
               'message' => $body
              );

              $ch = curl_init();
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
              $result = curl_exec($ch);
              $result = http_build_query($result, TRUE);
              curl_close($ch);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rochelle i really appreciate the help but the code gives me this error below via Code Snippets: 


`Don't Panic  The code snippet you are trying to save produced a fatal error on line 15: syntax error, unexpected ';'  `

Comment: Sorry Kobbe! I believe it's fixed.  It was missing a ')'

Comment: Yea..i figured, Thanks once again

Comment: Now I need to get multiple recipients so i used gravity wiz nested form so i have created another form with id 29 and have added the phone field with id 9 but I've tried all i could but get the nested form value including:

 $phone_numbers = array();
 $nested_entries = GFAPI::get_entries($form['id'], array("status" => "active"));
 foreach ($nested_entries as $nested_entry) {
  $phone_numbers[] = str_replace("+1", "0", $nested_entry['9']);
 }

Please anyone with knowledge on how to get the value should help me. Thanks

@Rochelle